# Pdf docs not viewable on amazon cloud

Tags: kindle, amazon

"My Send-to-Kindle Docs" folder available at https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/folder/ does not contain docs I've converted to kindle via sending a pdf to kindle email account. I can view the docs via my kindle app on Android and iPad. Is this a bug where these docs are not viewable on amazon.com ?